# Getting a date value from first column and first row of a table

Tags: vba

I tried getting a date value from a 1st column and 1st row of a table, just like this:

```
Dim objStartDate As Date
objStartDate = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("Date").ListRows(1).Value
```

But got this error message:

```
Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

What's the correct way to get value(s) from a table?

Comment: If you actually have a list object, then `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("Date").Range.Cells(2).Value`.

Comment: You can also try this: `ActiveSheet.Range("Table1[Date]")(1).Value` where 1 indicates that you want to retrieve the 1st data under Date Column. To get the header, use 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to post GSerg's and my comment as answer to help others which might be having same issue.

**From GSerg's comment:**

"If you actually have a list object, then" - *GSerg*

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("Date").Range.Cells(2).Value
```

You can also drop *Cells* property and directly access data using *Range*.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("Date").Range(2).Value
```

Or you can try what I've commented just using *Range Object.*

```
ActiveSheet.Range("Table1[Date]")(1).Value
```

Again this is assuming you actually have a *ListObject* named *Table1* with an existing *Date* Column.
HTH's anyone who have the same issue.

Comment: @GSerg You can strip your comment from my post and post is as actual answer anytime :)